# Fetch records from one table where there's not a record in another

Tags: sql, mysql, database

### `SURVEYS` table:

```
SurveyID
UserID
Question
Choice1
Choice2
Choice3
```

### `RESPONSES` table:

```
UserID
SurveyID
Answer
```

The first desire (achieved): Show me all surveys that User 28 has initiated:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Surveys 
 WHERE Surveys.UserID = 28
```

The second desire (achieved): Show me all surveys that User 28 has answered:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Surveys 
INNER JOIN Responses ON Surveys.SurveyID = Responses.SurveyID 
 WHERE Responses.UserID = 28
```

### The third desire (not achieved):

Show me all surveys that were NOT initiated by User 28 and which User 28 has NOT already answered... SELECT * FROM Surveys INNER JOIN Responses ON Surveys.SurveyID = Responses.SurveyID WHERE Surveys.UserID <> 28 AND Responses.UserID <> 28 [alternately: WHERE NOT Surveys.UserID = 28 OR Responses.UserID = 28]

The third query eliminates a record for User 28 but other instances of the same survey will appear. For instance, let's say that User 29 answered the survey. A row would be returned because the WHERE doesn't prohibit User 29's record.

I thought of using a subquery -- something like: SELECT * FROM Surveys WHERE Surveys.UserID <> 28 AND Surveys.SurveyID <> (SELECT Responses.SurveyID WHERE Responses.UserID = 28) -- but that doesn't work because the sub-query can easily produce more than one row.

What's the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Using NOT IN:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM SURVEYS s
 WHERE s.userid != 28
   AND s.surveyid NOT IN (SELECT r.survey_id
                            FROM RESPONSES r
                           WHERE r.userid = 28)
```

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

```
   SELECT s.*
     FROM SURVEYS s
LEFT JOIN RESPONSES r ON r.survey_id = s.surveyid
                     AND r.user_id = 28
    WHERE s.userid != 28
      AND r.userid IS NULL
```

### Using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT s.*
  FROM SURVEYS s
 WHERE s.userid != 28
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                     FROM RESPONSES r
                    WHERE r.userid = 28
                      AND r.survey_id = s.surveyid)
```

Of the options listed, the `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` are equivalent though I prefer the `NOT IN` because it is more readable.

Comment: For more info on the comparison of the operations, see: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I think should do?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Surveys s
WHERE s.UserID != 28 
AND s.SurveyID NOT IN (SELECT R.SurveyID FROM Responses R WHERE R.UserID = 28)
```