# Return records from one table where Field not found in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm so lost here I don't even know how to best title my question.

I am creating a simple dating site.  I want the women to be able to block the men just like all other dating sites.  When this happens, I don't want the womens' profiles to be returned in a query.

Table A
Members table containing all the profile information including a member name
Table B
Blocked members table containing the woman's name and the man's name for each case in which the woman has blocked a man

So, I want something like this:
$query = Return all records from table A where sex=female and there is no record in table B containing the woman's name and the man's name

I thought I would run a query against table B to retrieve all women who have blocked me, then run a query against table A to return all females in which the woman's username is NOT contained in the results of my first query.  However, I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: what you have tried so far?? hope you must have tried something. please tell us where you are facing problem... Also provide Table A & B structure...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetch records from one table where there's not a record in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983790/fetch-records-from-one-table-where-theres-not-a-record-in-another)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question...seems like a simple join, no? Not sure if I'm misunderstanding. Something like this perhaps:

`SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT BLOCK_ID FROM table2)`

So `Table1` has all ID's of the women, and `Table2` has all block id's (for example) and you want what is not in that? Obviously some changes required on top of this.

Comment: Works perfectly!!!  Thanks for the help.  I had the general idea, but didn't know the syntax.  I didn't know how to write the second query like that.  Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to see a list of all the female members who had blocked the current user, you would use a query like:

```
SELECT member.*
FROM TableA member
JOIN TableB blocked ON (member.name = blocked.user_who_blocked)
WHERE member.sex = female
    AND blocked.blocked_user_name = 'Joe McCurrentUser'
;
```

So, if you want to see the set of users where that is **not** the case, you use a LEFT JOIN and look for a null id.

```
SELECT member.*
FROM TableA member
LEFT JOIN TableB blocked ON (member.name = blocked.user_who_blocked)
WHERE member.sex = female
    AND blocked.blocked_user_name = 'Joe McCurrentUser'
    AND blocked.id IS NULL
;
```

You can modify as you wish to use the actual columns in your tables.  Make sure you have indices on both the user_who_blocked and blocked_user_name columns in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
Select * from Table A
inner join Table B on a.womans_name = B.womans_name and B.mans_name="Mans Name"
where B.womans_name IS NULL
```

If Table B contains a record with the matching womans_name and mans_name then the join will create one record containing all the fields in Table A and Table B *but* the Where clause will reject this record because the womans_name from Table B will not be null. If Table B does not contain a matching record then all those fields will be null (including B.womans_name) so the Where clause is satisfied.